# Spark Scala: How to replace null with values from an array or another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as below

```scala
+-----+------+
|empID|deptid|
+-----+------+
|  163|  null|
|  843|  null|
+-----+------+
```

And I have and Array of Long number `range = [20,21]` or you can convert it to another dataframe as

```scala
+--------+
|  deptid|
+--------+
|      20|
|      21|
+--------+
```

I want to replace those null values and get the output as

```scala
+-----+------+
|empID|deptid|
+-----+------+
|  163|    20|
|  843|    21|
+-----+------+
```

I tried

```
emp.na.fill(range, Array("deptid")
```

But na.fill needs the first parameter to be String Boolean Long double etc, and not an array.

I tried to join two dataframes to get the output but non of the joins give me the solution.

Everything I try gives me

```
+-----+------+
|empID|deptid|
+-----+------+
|  163|  null|
|  843|  null|
| null|     5|
| null|     6|
+-----+------+
```

Any idea?

Edit: It does not matter which empId get's which value from range array.

And yes I have made sure the array length matches the number of nulls.

Comment: Do you know that the array length will the the same as the amount of nulls in your dataframe? Does it matter which member of the array is matched with which null?

Comment: @SainingLi It does not matter which empId get's which value from range array.
And yes I have made sure the array length matches the number of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

So I do have a solution for this but it's so convoluted and hacky that I still want someone to give a better answer.

Basically join two dataframes, collect all data as array zip (removes all null values) and then explode as mapped values.

```
val p = newRecords.as("L")
.join(range.as("R"), newRecords("deptid") =!= range("deptid"), "full")
.groupBy()
.agg(collect_list($"R.deptid").as("D"), collect_list($"empID").as("E"))
.withColumn("zip",arrays_zip(col("D"),col("E"))).drop("D", "E")
.select(explode($"zip").as("zip1"))
.withColumn("empid", $"zip1".getItem("E"))
.withColumn("deptid", $"zip1".getItem("D"))
.drop($"zip1")
.show()

+-----+------+
|empid|deptid|
+-----+------+
|  163|    20|
|  843|    21|
+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with or without converting the array into a dataframe. Might be worth trying out both to see which is more efficient (usually udfs will be slower).

If you don't convert the array into a dataframe, you can use a udf. You'd generate row numbers for the initial dataframe and use it as an index into the array:

```
val testDF = Seq((163, null), (843, null)).toDF("empID", "deptID")
val range = List(20, 21)

val myUDF = udf((i: Int) => {
    range(i)
})

testDF.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("empID")) - 1)
.withColumn("deptID", myUDF(col("rn")))
.select("empID", "deptID").show
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+
|empID|deptID|
+-----+------+
|  163|    20|
|  843|    21|
+-----+------+
```

If you do convert the array into a dataframe, you can generate row numbers for both the dataframes and use that in your join condition:

```
val testDF = Seq((163, null), (843, null)).toDF("empID", "deptID")
val rangeDF = Seq(20, 21).toDF("deptID")

testDF.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("empID")))
.join(rangeDF.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("deptID"))), Seq("rn"))
.select(testDF.col("empID"), rangeDF.col("deptID")).show
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+
|empID|deptID|
+-----+------+
|  163|    20|
|  843|    21|
+-----+------+
```

Note that both these solutions involve using a `Window` function without a partition defined. This could be bad if you have a lot of data and it end up getting shuffled to a single node.